making esbuild treeshake with sideEffects:false
We have an Angular 18 application that used to be build with webpack. In our webpack.config.js file, we had this:
module.exports = (config, _options, targetOptions) => {
    config.module.rules = [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            /**
             * Declares all questionnaire ESM modules are safe to remove if completely unused.
             * This is tested to be relatively safe for the questionnaire project,
             * and adding new code that contains side effects should be avoided as much as possible.
             */
            sideEffects: false,
        },
        ...config.module.rules,
    ];

Now we moved to esbuild, and we want it to handle all files the same way - as they are of the nature sideEffects: false
How can I do that? I tried this way:
const sideEffectsPlugin = {
        name: 'sideEffects',
        setup(build) {
            build.onLoad({ filter: /\.ts$/ }, async (args) => {
                const source = await require('fs').promises.readFile(
                    args.path,
                    'utf8',
                );
                return {
                    contents: source,
                    loader: 'ts',
                    sideEffects: false, // Set sideEffects to false for .ts files
                };
            });
        },
    };

But it does not seem to work.
Thanks.
